# Address sanitizer and __attribute(section("mysection")) failing

Tags: c, clang, address-sanitizer

I'm using [a library](https://github.com/rustyrussell/ccan/tree/master/ccan/autodata) to register some structs at compile time. In this case it's registering a struct representing a JSON-RPC method that I'd like to expose. The library marks the structs with `__attribute(section("xautodata_" "somename"))` so that it'll be put in a separate section that can later be retrieved. The generated content will look like this:

```
static const autodata_json_command_ *__attribute__((__used__)) __attribute__((section("xautodata_" "json_command"))) autodata_json_command_151 = (&help_command);;
static const autodata_json_command_ *__attribute__((__used__)) __attribute__((section("xautodata_" "json_command"))) autodata_json_command_173 = (&stop_command);;
```

The code that later retrieves the commands will get a pointer to the section (and count the number of elements in that section) and iterate over it, like this:

```
size_t count;
struct json_command **commands = get_json_commands(&count);
for (size_t i=0; i<count; i++) {
  // Access commands[i];
}
```

This works perfectly fine if we don't compile with `-fsanitize=address`, but it'll add padding when compiled with `-fsanitize=address`.

Without the address sanitizer commands are adjacent to each other, i.e., `commands[0]` and `commands[1]` are valid pointers to structs. With the sanitizer only every 8th command is a valid pointer (presumably due to padding).

Now for the real question: what's the cleanest way to fix this? Should I try to make the stepsize larger (in which case a preprocessor instruction is needed to distinguish the sanitizer use)? Or is there a way to disable this padding for things in the section?

Answer (score 3):

GCC Asan deliberately avoids instrumenting variables in custom sections for the reasons you outlined (i.e. to preserve consecutiveness):

```
/* Don't protect if using user section, often vars placed
   into user section from multiple TUs are then assumed
   to be an array of such vars, putting padding in there
   breaks this assumption.  */
  || (DECL_SECTION_NAME (decl) != NULL
  && !symtab_node::get (decl)->implicit_section
  && !section_sanitized_p (DECL_SECTION_NAME (decl)))
```

(from [gcc/asan.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/02aa6d736e7cff65277571746bc83c023edca947/gcc/asan.c#L1667)). A special flag `-fsanitize-sections=wildcard1,wildcard2,...` can be used to force instrumentation in this case.

Clang Asan on the other hand ignores user section annotations (see [AddressSanitizer.cpp](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/b49d1c1b41a5a918f0cf99b57a9c464698595397/lib/Transforms/Instrumentation/AddressSanitizer.cpp#L1681)).

I suggest to add a PR to [Asan tracker](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues) to either make Clang behave like GCC or add a special flag to control instrumentation of user sections (in latter case we also need to update [Asan Clang/GCC incompatibility wiki](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerClangVsGCC-(5.0-vs-7.1))).